# error: Azure.Messaging.EventHubs: The path to an Event Hub may be specified as part of the connection string or as a separate value, but not both

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

At first I upgraded the package "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.EventHubs" from version 4.3.0 to 5.1.0.
and I upgraded from the deprecated Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs package to Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.

Then I run the C# function that return the error: '**Azure.Messaging.EventHubs: The path to an Event Hub may be specified as part of the connection string or as a separate value, but not both.  Please verify that your connection string does not have the `EntityPath` token if you are passing an explicit Event Hub name. (Parameter 'connectionString').**'

I have [this settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbS4A.png)
and checked the EntityPath in connectionString is the same as the EventhubName.

My code:

```
[FunctionName("FilterFunctionEventhubTrigger")]
public async Task Run(
        [EventHubTrigger(
        "EventhubName",
        Connection = "EventhubConnection",
        ConsumerGroup = "%ConsumerGroup%")] EventData[] events, ILogger log)
{ ... }
```

Why the low version not return this error?

What need I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `EntityPath=abc` part from your connection string.

I think this error is to remove the situation where it would be ambiguous which one to use.
Of course in your case the value is the same, but they have done a simpler implementation where they throw an error if the event hub name is specified in different places.

Comment: This is correct.  The error appears only when two different Event Hubs are specified and it is unclear which you intended to use.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by change the 'Eventhubname' to use appsettings bindings.

```
 [FunctionName("FilterFunctionEventhubTrigger")]
public async Task Run(
        [EventHubTrigger(
        "EventhubName",
        Connection = "EventhubConnection",
        ConsumerGroup = "%ConsumerGroup%")] EventData[] events, ILogger log)
{ ... }
```

to

```
        [FunctionName("FilterFunctionEventhubTrigger")]
public async Task Run(
        [EventHubTrigger(
        eventHubName: "%EventHubName%", // <------ Provide like this
        Connection = "EventhubConnection",
        ConsumerGroup = "%ConsumerGroup%")] EventData[] events, ILogger log)
{ ... }
```

more information form https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/3034